# How to make a button stick to the Angular Material Sidenav?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, sidebar

With the Angular Material [sidenav](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav) I am trying to achieve a functionality similar to the one in [this](https://nnattawat.github.io/slideReveal/) control where the sidenav has a "sticky" button next to it which controls its state, changes shape based on it and moves with the sidebar itself. Are there Any implementations/examples for it?